# Number of ways to choose from 6 when 2 don't want to attend together.

Tags: probability-theory, combinations

Guys I'm solving this problem. This came from schaum's outline of probability.

A woman has 11 close friends. In how many ways can she invite 6 of them to dinner if two of them are not on speaking terms and will not attend together?

Here's my solution:

total number of ways = (number ways that either one of them attends but not both) * 2 + (number of ways that both of them don't attend)
= 9C5 * 2 + 9C6
= 336.

But the correct answer says 378 Where did I get wrong?

Comment: I think your answer is right and Schaum is wrong... my approach was $_{11} C_6 - ~_9 C_4$; the first term counts the number of all ways to invite guests, and the second term subtracts the ways that invite the feuding friends. I seem to reproduce your answer of 336.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is right.

Schaum actually meant invite $5$ friends.

$$\binom{9}{4}2+\binom{9}{5}= 378$$

Comment: Okay thank you guys. Now I have confirmed that my understanding is right.